Testing Angular 12 (node 12) with Jest v.27 lead to syntax problem with optional chaining
I use jest v.27 to test an Angular v.12 app (on Node 12). Migrating Angular or Node is not an option.package.json:
dependencies: 
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.0.3",
devDependecies:
    "jest": "^27.5.1",

tsConfig.spec.json:
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest","node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

setupJest.ts:
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
jestConfig.js:
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/setupJest.ts'],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['./node_modules/'],
}


Error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object. (/home/mp/Documents/Myelin/myelinEngine/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/compiler/ng-jest-compiler.js:5:25)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

I tried to use Babel to transform the optional chaining character:
package.json:
    devDependecies:
        "@babel/cli": "^7.24.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.24.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5",

jest.config.js:
    module.exports = {
        preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
        setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/setupJest.ts'],
        testPathIgnorePatterns: ['./node_modules/'],
        transform: {
            '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'babel-jest'
          }
      };

It doesn't change anything
In tsconfig.json, I tried to change lib and target to
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "target": "ES2020" 

but it didn't work

Optional chaining is an ES2020 feature, so if that's your target it won't be transpiled. For Node 12 you need to target ES2019.
